Under what circumstance can `sys.getrefcount()` return zero?
I was reading the Python 3.12 official documentation on the sys module, and the part about getrefcount() seems rather confusing to me (emphasis mine).

Return the reference count of the object. The count returned is
generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the
(temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().
Note that the returned value may not actually reflect how many
references to the object are actually held. For example, some objects
are “immortal” and have a very high refcount that does not reflect the
actual number of references. Consequently, do not rely on the returned
value to be accurate, other than a value of 0 or 1.

Changed in version 3.12: Immortal objects have very large refcounts
that do not match the actual number of references to the object.


When sys.getrefcount(expr) is invoked in Python, if nothing else, there is at least a reference to the object resulting from expr: the reference from getrefcount() itself. For example, the following code returns the minimal possible return value of getrefcount() per my understanding, which is 1.
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(object()))

I suspect this is a documentation inaccuracy due to a direct copy from the documentation of Py_REFCNT. Note how one paragraph duplicates exactly the same text as the previously quoted documentation.

Get the reference count of the Python object o.
Note that the returned value may not actually reflect how many
references to the object are actually held. For example, some objects
are “immortal” and have a very high refcount that does not reflect the
actual number of references. Consequently, do not rely on the returned
value to be accurate, other than a value of 0 or 1.
Use the Py_SET_REFCNT() function to set an object reference count.

Changed in version 3.10: Py_REFCNT() is changed to the inline static
function.


Changed in version 3.11: The parameter type is no longer const PyObject*.


In the case of Py_REFCNT() I believe it's reasonable to return a value of zero because passing a pointer to Py_REFCNT() does not automatically form an additional reference to the underlying Python object. However, I do not believe that there can be a case where the getrefcount() function from Python sys module can possibly return zero.
Am I missing anything obvious or any edge cases? Is there a case where sys.getrefcount() can return zero as the documentation currently seem to allude to? It would be better if someone can further clarify what the bolded sentence actually means. Does it mean that a sys.getrefcount() return value of 3 (which is a rather common case) should be considered inaccurate?

From what I gathered, getrefcount() can't return 0. Possible issue with (roughly) duplicating the PY_REFCNT function documentation. While doing tests, I stumbled several times

upon 3 with inline strings (e.g sys.getrefcount("dkzkzjdkdjd")), which means (to me) it isn't to be trusted, as you'd obviously expect 1 as a value (that one pointer passed to sys.getrefcount). I doubt it fully answer your question, however.

That is explained in this answer. If there are indeed 3 references and the function returns 3, I don't consider it inaccurate, just that the language is more intricate than expected. I suppose the "Consequently, do not rely... accurate" to refer to something else, but I may be wrong.
